# Make radio button uncheck itself when clicking on it with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

For a set of radio buttons where the 2nd of 3 options is checked, how can I make it un-check when clicking on the checked option (the same behavior as as unchecking a checkbox)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? That's not how radio buttons are supposed to work. If you want to clear all the options, I suggest a separate `Clear` button.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dummy radio option and hide it with display:none

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" style="display:none" value="other">
</form>
```

Then your JS would be:

```
var currentValue;
  $('form>input').click(function(){
    if(currentValue===$(this).val())     {
      $(this).parent().find('input:last-child').click();
      currentValue=$(this).parent().find('input:last-child').val();
    }
    else{
      currentValue=$(this).val()
    }
  });
```

In JS we check if the click was on actual checked option and if so, it chooses the dummy option so the radio 'unchecks' visually. Hope that helps you.